# Treepanel node row index

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I have a treepanel with some set of nodes. 
I'm searching the node using my own criteria.
When node is found i want to select cell on row which contains node.

I can select cell using

`cellSelectionModel.setCurrentPosition({row: row, column: column});`

but i can't understand how get the row index of node.

Thanx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have model record, from store:

```
var rowNumber = store.indexOf(record);
```

Comment: Yes, it works like that: `var rowNumber = node.store.indexOf(node)`